# Spatie Laravel Permission Error of Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, laravel

I need help with spatie/Laravel permissions. when I try to assign roles gives me this error 
`Too few arguments to function Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::handle(), 2 passed in C:\Users\user pc\Documents\website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php on line 171 and exactly 3 expected`

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below link. Maybe you will get your desire result.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/871